# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\GenericMetadata::addConstraint() must be an instance, string given

Tags: php, symfony

I set up automatic wiring in the Symfony 3.4 app.

When I tried to change the status of the article during the operation check the error below occurred.

Is it possible that the automatic wiring settings cause this?

Error message:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to 
Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\GenericMetadata::addConstraint()
must be an instance of 
Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, string given, called in
/home/vagrant/Symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/GenericMetadata.php on line 159

  at Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\TraceableValidator->validate(object(Coordinate), array('Default', 'Strict'))
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Model/Service/ArticleService.php:173)
  at App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\ArticleService->App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\{closure}(object(EntityManager))
  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(EntityManager))
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:240)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->transactional(object(Closure))
     (var/cache/dev/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_602cd1ba7a6bd.php:21)
  at EntityManager602cd1ba7a6bd_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->transactional(object(Closure))
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Model/Service/ArticleService.php:183)
  at App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\ArticleService->updateArticleStatus(array('3990'), 'pending', object(Shop))
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller/BaseArticleController.php:434)
  at App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\BaseArticleController->updateArticleStatusAction(object(Request), object(ArticleService), array('3990'))
     (src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller/Shop/ArticleController.php:137)
  at App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Shop\ArticleController->updateArticleStatusAction(object(Request), object(ArticleService), '3990')
```

ArticleService.php

```php
   /**
     * Article status change
     * @param array|integer|string $id ID of the article to be deleted
     * @param $articleStatus
     * @param Shop $shop shop
     * @return integer Number of articles whose status has changed
     */
    public function updateArticleStatus($id, $articleStatus, $shop = null)
    {
        // Article ID for status change
        $ids = is_array($id) ? $id : array($id);

        $ret = $this->entityManager->transactional(function () use ($ids, $articleStatus, $shop) {
            // Obtain validators and validation groups
            $validationGroups = $this->getValidationGroups($articleStatus);

            $count = 0;
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $article = $this->getArticle($id, $shop);
                if ($article && $article->getArticleStatus() != $articleStatus) {
                    // Change status
                    $article->setArticleStatus($articleStatus);

                    // Validation
                    //line 173
                    $errors = $this->validator->validate($article, $validationGroups);
                    if (count($errors) > 0) {
                        throw new ArticleValidationException($article, (array)$errors);
                    }

                    // Count articles whose status has changed
                    $count++;
                }
            }
            return $count;
        });
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit more of the stack trace? There must be a reason why a string instead of a constraint is passed the wrong way in your method. It is hard to tell whats the error without more detailed information.

Comment: @Blackbam Thank you for your comment. Added stacktrace. I got an error saying that there is too much code, so I deleted the other code. Please check the stacktrace and if you have any code you would like to see, please tell me again.

Comment: Maybe an issue with src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Model/Service/ArticleService.php:173 ? What is passed there, could it cause the error? Sorry this problem is hard to debug remotely, the possible causes of the error are quite broad afaik.

Comment: @Blackbam Added code. That part is the part that was changed from  ``` $validator = $ this->container->get('validator'); ``` to ```__construct``` by passing an argument to  ```$ this->validator``` . That may have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown below, I solved it by changing the validator so that it works only when the parameter is acquired by `isset`.

```php
                if ($article && $article->getArticleStatus() != $articleStatus) {
                    $article->setArticleStatus($articleStatus);
                   
                    if (isset($article->getPublishDateTime)){
                       $errors = $validator->validate($article, $validationGroups);
                           
                      if (count($errors) > 0) {
                        throw new ArticleValidationException($article, $errors);
                      }
                    }
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean validation is only done when publishDateTime is not null?

Comment: @CzarPino Validation should work if it is not null or if you have set the variable to a value (including blanks, array ()).

Comment: I see. Thanks. That is weird though. I think the validator should be able to deal with nulls though since we sometimes need null properties/columns.

Comment: @CzarPino  ```$article->getPublishDateTime``` can be NULL, and it doesn't matter if it is null.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it turned out to be an incorrect assumption (on my end) of the arguments of the validate method. The interface of validate method from ValidatorInterface is,

```php
public function validate($value, $constraints = null, $groups = null);
```

And so,

```php
$error = $validator->validate($entity, $groups);
```

Should be

```php
$error = $validator->validate($entity, null, $groups);
```